# Excel Formular - SUMPRODUCT on multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to use `SUMPRODUCT` to find value on multiple worksheet?

Below are the the formular I am currently using but it only find the value on one sheet.

`=SUMPRODUCT((APRIL!L:L="AB")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"F/W"};APRIL!E:E;1)))`

Also, how do I adapt it so the formula only find the exact word when searching for value?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `SUMPRODUCT` you can reference multiple sheets at once using notation `Sheet1:Sheet3!A1:A3`. It than takes range `A1:A3` from `Sheet1`, `Sheet3` and any Sheets in between the two. So it's important to keep other sheets out of the start and end sheet, or they'll be included in the sumproduct.

In your case it would be something like:
`=SUMPRODUCT((JANUARY:APRIL!L:L="AB")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"F/W"};JANUARY:APRIL!E:E;1)))`

Note that you're using SEARCH and say you want exact match. Search is not case sensitive FIND is.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can use `SUMPRODUCT` to find a value on multiple worksheets. To do so, you could use the recently added `VSTACK` and `HSTACK` functions that allow you to merge different ranges into one. There are a few caveats upfront:

- You cannot use this formula with unspecified range size, so no (L:L) or (E:E), it needs to be a specific size i.e. (L2:L5000)
- Finally, you need to consider that this puts a strain on the computer as it has to access the data from the worksheet by accessing the data via a link, which opens the workbook as a background process.

  ```
   =SUMPRODUCT((VSTACK(APRIL!L1:L5000;[Book1]APRIL!L1:L5000; 'C:\temp;[Book2]APRIL'!L1:L5000="AB")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"F/W"};APRIL!E1:E5000;[Book1]APRIL!E1:E5000; 'C:\temp\[Book2]APRIL'!E1:E5000;1)))
  ```

Finally, to do a case sensitive Search, you could use the `EXACT` function as such as:

`SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(lookup_value; criteria_range); value_range)`.

This will allow a case-sensitive search for text strings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, the search is happening within the active workbook.

Regarding the below formular, as I have two value as SFX and SFX/FW.

Comment: @TK4795 Sorry, I didn't get that, so you want the formula to return "SFX" and not "SFX/FW"?